# AWS CodePipeline github webhook not triggering on commit

Tags: github, aws-cli, aws-codepipeline, git-webhooks

I set up an AWS CodePipeline that uses github as a source, CodeBuild for build, and deploys to ElasticBeanstalk.

I was able to get it working when everything was set up in the console and I was an admin of the github account (I used a different account for testing)

The actual code I need to deploy belongs to an account where I am not an admin so following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/GitHub-create-personal-token-CLI.html) I received a Personal Access Token and updated the CodePipeline using the CLI.

Once i updated the project using the cli, it no longer gets triggered when the code is committed.

I'm not sure what changed, because it still doesn't work even when I use the console and set up the webhook directly as an admin of the github account I was testing with.

This is the json I updated the pipeline with:

```
{
    "pipeline": {
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/service-role/AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-us-west-2-xxxxx-xxxx", 
        "stages": [
            {
                "name": "Source", 
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "inputArtifacts": [], 
                        "name": "Source", 
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Source", 
                            "owner": "ThirdParty", 
                            "version": "1", 
                            "provider": "GitHub"
                        }, 
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "configuration": {
                            "Owner": "xxx", 
                            "Repo": "xxx", 
                            "PollForSourceChanges": "false", 
                            "Branch": "stage"
                        }, 
                        "runOrder": 1
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Build", 
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "name": "Build", 
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Build", 
                            "owner": "AWS", 
                            "version": "1", 
                            "provider": "CodeBuild"
                        }, 
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildArtifact"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "configuration": {
                            "ProjectName": "xxx-stage-codebuild"
                        }, 
                        "runOrder": 1
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Deploy", 
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildArtifact"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "name": "Deploy", 
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Deploy", 
                            "owner": "AWS", 
                            "version": "1", 
                            "provider": "ElasticBeanstalk"
                        }, 
                        "outputArtifacts": [], 
                        "configuration": {
                            "ApplicationName": "xxx", 
                            "EnvironmentName": "xxx-stage"
                        }, 
                        "runOrder": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ], 
        "artifactStore": {
            "type": "S3", 
            "location": "xxx-artifacts-stage"
        }, 
        "name": "xxx-stage", 
        "version": 15
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To fix the webhook for the updated GitHub source, you need to perform the following steps:

1. Use the steps in [1] to deregister and delete the existing webhook that is associated with the old GitHub repository.
2. Use the steps in [2] to recreate the webhook.

Ref:

[1] Delete the Webhook for Your GitHub Source - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-webhooks-delete.html

[2] Create a Webhook for a GitHub Source - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-webhooks-create.html

Let me know if you come across any challenges.

Comment: I'm following the create guide, but i'm getting a 'Not found' error when calling register-webhook-with-third-party. Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: You answer help me on a pipeline built with cdk v2!
cdk destroy then cdk deploy fixed the trigger on code commit.